# How to get list of local videos and display them in grid format in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-development, camera-roll

I am trying to do something similar to what Instagram has for their select video screen. Where a grid of local videos that can be uploaded and it'll kind of 'preview' the one that is currently selected above the grid itself.

I'm using the react-native-community/cameraroll and this is the code I'm trying to get the Videos with.

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({first: 20, assetType: "All"})
        .then(r => this.setState({ videos: r.edges }))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('getVideosErr:' + err)
        })
```

and I am trying to display the grid with some sample code I found and tried playing around with:

```
<ScrollView>
     {this.state.videos.map((p, i) => {
          return (
           <Video
              key={i}
              style={{
              width: 300,
              height: 100,
           }}
            source={{ uri: p.node.video.uri }}
            />
        ;
})}
```

I have one video on the simulator but I am getting an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'uri' of undefined" everytime I try grabbing the video.

Not so sure what the issue is right now, I followed the samples on the documentation for the cameraroll but haven't had any luck yet. Any advice/examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-native-media-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-media-helper)

implementation:

```
import MediaHelper from 'react-native-media-helper'

  <MediaHelper
    numVideos={20} // for android
    media='Videos'   // for ios
    num={20}      // for ios
    onCancel={() => this.setState({visible: false})}
    onSelectedItem={(item) => alert(JSON.stringify(item))}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because node object doesn't have any video property. The video files are also stored under image property. Consider changing your code to this to get rid of the null exception.

```
<ScrollView>
   {this.state.videos.map((p, i) => {
      return (
        <Image
          key={i}
          style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 100,
          }}
          source={{uri: p.node.image.uri}}
        />
   })
}
```

Also since you only want videos, I would recommend specifying the assetType to only be 'Videos'

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({first: 20, assetType: "Videos"})
        .then(r => this.setState({ videos: r.edges }))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('getVideosErr:' + err)
        })
```